# Order List Object in same order as another list in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a `List` object as following:

```
  var list1 = new List<DummyObject> {
        new DummyObject { ID="1", UniqueCode="ltrasd8ShFwNEyWrPTd9jIJJQ" },
        new DummyObject { ID="2", UniqueCode="GB456rpcpxRYEeOr32w5oRMwg" },
        new DummyObject { ID="3", UniqueCode="Y7twLumNJU6dQZLR0KxqA"     },
        new DummyObject { ID="4", UniqueCode="nG3vejzzxkiO21oDt58vkw"    },
        new DummyObject { ID="5", UniqueCode="aPwwG1JMYUGTvOL2lG0YFg"    },            
    }
```

and another `List` object definition with Ids is:

```
   List<int> list2  = new List<int>() { 2, 4, 5, 1, 3 };
```

I want to order the `list1` by the `list2` and the result should be as following:

```
    var output= new List<DummyObject> {
        new DummyObject { ID="2", UniqueCode="ltrasd8ShFwNEyWrPTd9jIJJQ" },
        new DummyObject { ID="4", UniqueCode="GB456rpcpxRYEeOr32w5oRMwg" },
        new DummyObject { ID="5", UniqueCode="Y7twLumNJU6dQZLR0KxqA"     },
        new DummyObject { ID="1", UniqueCode="nG3vejzzxkiO21oDt58vkw"    },
        new DummyObject { ID="3", UniqueCode="aPwwG1JMYUGTvOL2lG0YFg"    },            
    }
```

Can anyone please guide me here how to acheive this using `LINQ`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the lists are small, then you can do it like this:

```
var result = list1.OrderBy(x => list2.IndexOf(Convert.ToInt32(x.ID))).ToList();
```

If the lists are large, then the following solution will perform better:

```
//Create a dictionary that maps the integer values of the IDs to the objects
var dictionary = list1.ToDictionary(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ID), x => x);

var result = list2.Select(x => dictionary[x]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with LINQ like this:

```
var output = list1.OrderBy(dummyObject => list2.IndexOf(int.Parse(dummyObject.ID))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Join` preserves the order of the elements of outer sequence (`list2`), and for each of its elements, the order of the matching elements of inner sequence (`list1`)

```
var output = list2.Join(list1, i => i.ToString(), o => o.ID, (i,o) => o)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var _orderedList = (from l2 in list2 join l1 in list1 on l2 equals int.Parse(l1.ID) select l1).ToList();
```